# Parsing lines from text file

Tags: c#, streamreader

I am reading 2 input parameter form same text file `input.txt` which are separated by using *'#'* like:

> 12#15
>
> 17#77
>
> 31#12

i have used this syntax but it reads last line only.why it isn't working? what may be the best loop condition to read line bye line like 12+15 and show 27 and read next line 17+71 and show 88 and process last

```
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader("input.txt");
            string line;
            int count = 0;
            while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                string[] splitted = line.Split('#');
                string first = splitted[0].Trim();
                string second = splitted[1].Trim();
                x = Convert.ToInt32(first);
                y = Convert.ToInt32(second);
```

Please help me with `StreamReader` syntax.

Comment: you can `Help Yourself` by doing a simple `Google Search on Read TextFile and Split on Delimiter` very basic

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In short, you can read the lines of the file using `StreamReader` and then use `string.Split()` and `int.Parse()` methods to extract the data.

You can read the file into a string using `StreamReader`.

```
string text;
using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("file.txt"))
    text = sr.ReadToEnd();
string[] parts = text.Replace("\r", string.Empty).Split('#', '\n');
txtA.Text = (int.Parse(parts[0]) + int.Parse(parts[1]).ToString();
txtB.Text = (int.Parse(parts[2]) + int.Parse(parts[3]).ToString();
```

Comment: recently i've updated the question please review and answer it